# Get network packets directly from network driver

Tags: performance

So, when a packet reaches a machine it is processed by the driver, then passed to the kernel yadda yadda until it reaches a program. I know all the perfectly sound reasons why this happens, but this obviously causes a time overhead.

For a pure performance system, is it possible to have a program read the driver directly, and get packets directly from it instead of getting them from the kernel?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: it depends. [So] answer: too broad.

Comment: Sure, I add to the question "how can you do it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! And you are not the first one to think about that. Some suggestions are:

PF_RING (linux):
http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/

netmap (freebsd):
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netmap&sektion=4

Intel (badass) DPDK:
http://dpdk.org/

This is also a good reading, that you might find interesting:
http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html

Comment: Thanks. The linux site is down :( does it explain how to do it?

Comment: Yep. Tutorials, manuals and a lot of documentation. Try getting a cached version while it's down: http://www.cachedpages.com

Comment: On curiosity of a different approach, could the driver be done to connect directly to a program?

Comment: That's exactly what DPDK can do. You can use it as a network driver, so the OS doesn't even see the network card as a network card. It's just a "DEV_WHATEVER", that the driver is handling. You have direct access to the driver API, and can get/send packets from there.
You should also watch the video on the last link of the answer, it's brilliant.